# How to leave a comment to Locked Post? OR: please unlock this question

Tags: support, locked-question

There is a [locked question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11178/112436) where I would like to leave a comment ("I think this question would work well at Language Learners Beta; if you repost there, please notify me").

I can't leave a comment and I can't edit the post.  Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question on meta doesn't need to be unlocked; you can simply leave your comment on the [original question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/429262/191178) on the main site (which is unlocked).

Update: The question on main has been deleted by its owner, but it looks like you were able to leave that comment before that happened.

---

When a post is locked due to a rejected migration, the revision history is linked in "migration rejected from [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/429262/revisions) *N* hours ago", which is in the banner underneath the post:

> [image: Picture of the banner]

From there, simply click "Return to Question", which should be at the very top of the revisions history (if the question is deleted and you don't have 10k rep, you will not see this):

> [image: Return to Question//Migration Rejected//Post Unlocked//Post Locked//Post Migrated Away//Post Closed as Off-Topic]

If you’re in the app, your first step is to get out of it and into a browser. The mobile site works the same way as the full desktop site; the only difference is the [appearance of the locked notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5J7U.jpg), which is very slightly different.

Comment: Thank you, will do.  Would be nice if a link to the original question appeared somewhere on the locked page....

Comment: @aparente001 "migration rejected from [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/429262/revisions) 6 hours ago" links to the revision history of the question. From there, click on "Return to Question".

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: All links lead me to the meta rejected page, not the original. What am I missing?

Comment: @NVZ I don't know... Are you sure you're clicking the right links? I added some images to show the process, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Still no. The "return to question" link in the revision page redirects to the locked meta. So I found a workaround - adding `?=noredirect` to the end of the URL takes me to the original main site Q.

Comment: NVZ  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429262/english-phrases-search-engine#comment1030692_429262